# simplexml_load_string loses the order of tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following XML:

```
<mobapp>    
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="target" id="target" value="" maxlength="8" required="true" pattern="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
        <label for="target"> Phone number</label> 
        <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" min="0" maxlength="16" required="true"/> 
        <label for="amount"> Amount to load:</label> 
    </form> 
</mobapp>
```

When I use `simplexml_load_string($theXML)` I get the following:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#150 (3) {
  ["input"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0] => object(SimpleXMLElement)#146 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=> [... removed for brevity ...]
    }
    [1] => object(SimpleXMLElement)#146 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=> [... removed for brevity ...]
    }
}
["label"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0] => [... removed for brevity ...]
    [1] => [... removed for brevity ...]

}
```

(I removed all the attributes to make it simpler to understand)

So I get an array of 2 "input" and an array of 2 "label", but I don't know the order in which they were in the XML.

Is there a way to get that order?

Comment: As far as I know, the `keys` of the XML array are the tags. So if you have 4 `<input ...` they'll still be under one `key: input`, without any "care" about the order in the original xml.

Comment: BTW, I don't know if it's happened when you copied the code but check out the ending your xml code: `</<mobapp>`, while it should be `</mobapp>`

Comment: @OfirBaruch Nope, they're not actually "in" that key at all, and there aren't really any arrays; that's just the way the debug output shows (and one way you *can* access them).

Comment: So while that output shows no sign for "storing" the order of the inputs, there's still a way to output those elements in their original order?

Comment: @OfirBaruch fixed the issue. Was an error when it was copied and edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I get an array of ...

No, you don't. SimpleXML is an object, not an array; what's more, it's an object designed to be used as an API, not one with fixed properties. When you use `print_r`, `var_dump`, or anything like that, it represents itself as though it's an object with a bunch of arrays inside, but that's not actually what is happening.

The reason it shows that, is that if you access `$simplexml_object->input`, you can loop through all the `<input>` elements, in the order they appear, which is often useful.

However, to loop through all the elements, regardless of their tag name, use [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and then check the name of each using [the `->getName()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getname.php), e.g.:

```
foreach ( $simplexml_object->children() as $node ) { 
    $tag_name = $node->getName();
    $text_content = (string)$node;
}
```