# Loading docx (xml) into php array not working as expected. I want to keep original order

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I'm trying to load a word (docx) document from PHP and it "kind of works"...

**This code would produce an array from the document.xml part of the word-document:**

```
$result = file_get_contents( 'zip://test.docx#word/document.xml' );
$content_arr = simplexml_load_string($result,null, 0, 'w', true);
```

BUT the nodes would rearranged when getting into the array with `simplexml_load_string` (and I don't want this rearrangement), where each node-type seems to be sorted out:

**from:**

```
p: some text
tbl: table
p: some text
p: some text
p: some text
```

**to:**

```
p: some text
p: some text
p: some text
p: some text
tbl: table
```

I would like something like this (that actually reflects the original order of the xml-nodes):

```
item0: p: some text
item1: tbl: table
item2: p: some text
item3: p: some text
item4: p: some text
```

**Is this possible or is `simplexml_load_string` simply wrong function to use for my purpose?**

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698192/simplexml-load-string-loses-the-order-of-tags

Comment: Thx, I actually did find a much better solution. I would post it soon :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is. SimpleXML does not work well with mixed child nodes (text and element siblings). So it does not work with complex XML formats like OOXML.

Reading data from OOXML with DOM+Xpath is actually quite easy:

```
$xml = <<<"XML"
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
    <w:body>
      <w:p>one</w:p>
      <w:p>two</w:p>
      <w:tbl>three</w:tbl>
      <w:p>four</w:p>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register a prefix for the used namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace(
  'word', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
);

// iterate any p and tbl element nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//word:p|//word:tbl') as $index => $node) {
    echo "item{$index} {$node->localName}: {$node->textContent}\n";
}
```

Output:

```
item0 p: one 
item1 p: two 
item2 tbl: three 
item3 p: four
```

Comment: Oh thx a lot for this! How can i retrieve all childs for each p? and all child for each tbl?

Comment: I imagine you mean inside the loop.  `$childNodes = $xpath->evaluate(`*|text()`, $node);` will retrieve any element or text child (but no comments). Read up about Xpath - it's powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a function in php that would really make my day (**and I hope it will make yours if you have the same issue that I had**). Actually I think it would be much easier to implement now (and debug) because the way the xml is converted into the array(s).

The function is `xml_parse_into_struct`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

```
$result = file_get_contents( 'zip://' . $file . '#word/document.xml' );

$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $result, $content_arr, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);

var_dump($content_arr);
```

**The dump looks like:**

```
array (size=1087)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag' => string 'W:DOCUMENT' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 1
      'attributes' => 
        array (size=20)
          'XMLNS:WPC' => string '{value}' (length=66)
          'XMLNS:CX' => string '{value}' (length=66)
          'XMLNS:CX1' => string '{value}' (length=60)
          'XMLNS:MC' => string '{value}' (length=59)
          'XMLNS:O' => string '{value}' (length=39)
          'XMLNS:R' => string '{value}' (length=67)
          'XMLNS:M' => string '{value}' (length=58)
          'XMLNS:V' => string '{value}' (length=29)
          'XMLNS:WP14' => string '{value}' (length=67)
          'XMLNS:WP' => string '{value}' (length=70)
          'XMLNS:W10' => string '{value}' (length=37)
          'XMLNS:W' => string '{value}' (length=60)
          'XMLNS:W14' => string '{value}' (length=52)
          'XMLNS:W15' => string '{value}' (length=52
          'XMLNS:W16SE' => string '{value}' (length=58)
          'XMLNS:WPG' => string '{value}' (length=65)
          'XMLNS:WPI' => string '{value}' (length=63)
          'XMLNS:WNE' => string '{value}' (length=52)
          'XMLNS:WPS' => string '{value}' (length=65)
          'MC:IGNORABLE' => string '{value}' (length=18)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:BODY' (length=6)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 2
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag' => string 'W:P' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 3
      'attributes' => 
        array (size=3)
          'W:RSIDR' => string '00DB5D45' (length=8)
          'W:RSIDRDEFAULT' => string '00DB5D45' (length=8)
          'W:RSIDP' => string '00DB5D45' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:PPR' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 4
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag' => string 'W:PSTYLE' (length=8)
      'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
      'level' => int 5
      'attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'W:VAL' => string 'Rubrik1' (length=7)
  5 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag' => string 'W:JC' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
      'level' => int 5
      'attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'W:VAL' => string 'center' (length=6)
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:PPR' (length=5)
      'type' => string 'close' (length=5)
      'level' => int 4
  7 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:R' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 4
  8 => 
    array (size=5)
      'tag' => string 'W:T' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
      'level' => int 5
      'attributes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'XML:SPACE' => string 'preserve' (length=8)
      'value' => string 'Skövde Konståkningsklubb inbjuder till ' (length=41)
  9 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:R' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'close' (length=5)
      'level' => int 4
  10 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:R' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 4
  11 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:BR' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
      'level' => int 5
  12 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag' => string 'W:T' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'complete' (length=8)
      'level' => int 5
      'value' => string 'dagläger i konståkning' (length=24)
  13 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:R' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'close' (length=5)
      'level' => int 4
  14 => 
    array (size=3)
      'tag' => string 'W:P' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'close' (length=5)
      'level' => int 3
  15 => 
    array (size=4)
      'tag' => string 'W:P' (length=3)
      'type' => string 'open' (length=4)
      'level' => int 3
      'attributes' => 
        array (size=3)
          'W:RSIDR' => string '00DB5D45' (length=8)
          'W:RSIDRDEFAULT' => string '00A14053' (length=8)
          'W:RSIDP' => string '00DB5D45' (length=8)
```